# How to implement the Google map API search autocomplete in React

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, autocomplete

I'm following the official guide of [google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) and trying to implement it in my react app as per the following:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles/locationInput.css';

export class locationInput extends Component {
    render() {
        const { values, handleChange } = this.props;

        function initAutocomplete() {
            var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
            var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

            var markers = [];
            searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
              var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

              if (places.length == 0) {
                return;
              }

              markers.forEach(function(marker) {
                marker.setMap(null);
              });
              markers = [];

              var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
              places.forEach(function(place) {
                if (!place.geometry) {
                  console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
                  return;
                }
                var icon = {
                  url: place.icon,
                  size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
                  origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                  anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
                  scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                };

                markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                  icon: icon,
                  title: place.name,
                  position: place.geometry.location
                }));

                if (place.geometry.viewport) {
                  bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
                } else {
                  bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
                }
              });

            });
          }
          initAutocomplete()
        return (

                <input
                    defaultValue={values.CollegeName}
                    onChange={handleChange('CollegeName')}
                    id="pac-input"
                    className="controls"
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Search Box"
                />

        );
    }
}

export default locationInput;
```

> I have initial the `<script>` in `index.html`

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
     async defer></script>
```

but I got this error
 **Failed to compile**

```
./src/public/form/lib-component/locationInput.js
  Line 10:24:  'google' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 25:23:  'google' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 33:17:  'google' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 34:19:  'google' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 35:19:  'google' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 36:23:  'google' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 39:22:  'google' is not defined  no-undef
Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

my question is when I tried to implement this code in plain `html` and `javascript` then it got worked flawlessly but not in react so how can I get it working here and how can i specify what `google` means here?

Comment: try new window.google.maps

Comment: Also, there is a good React component for this: https://github.com/hibiken/react-places-autocomplete

Comment: @ertemishakk i didnt got what did you meant by implementing `window.google.maps` could you please ellaborate more...

Comment: replace  ```new google.maps``` with ```new window.google.maps``` in your code.

Comment: @LáďaDurchánek I tried it but i was having an issue with integrating a state from other component to it and also it wasn't looking that great as the docs of gmap api

Comment: oh thanks @ertemishakk for helping me out it did worked out and I'll post answer below to highlight it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `new google.maps` with `new window.google.maps` in your code.